# How to run two Jenkins multi phase Jobs at the same time?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two groups of multi-phase jobs, `parallel test 1` and `parallel test 2`; where I need to execute both the groups together at the same time.

Does `multi job` jenkins plugin has a hack for it? or any alternatives...

**Note:** I don't want all the 3 jobs in the same `MultiJob Phase`

[image]

Comment: In the multi-job plugin, everything runs in parallel that is listed in the same "Phase". Just put those 3 jobs into one MultiJob Phase and you're set.

Comment: @RaoslawSzamszur Idea is to split 2 jobs in one phase and 1 job on another phase due to some internal project reasons

Comment: I'd figured it may be the case. Well, then the latest thing that comes into my mind is to rewrite your MultiJob logic into a declarative pipeline and use `[pararell](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel)`  block to run things in parallel. Is this doable for your project? I don't know any workarounds for such case for MultiJob.

Comment: @RaoslawSzamszur I believe this should help me; let me try :)

Comment: I can provide a dummy example of declarative pipeline if you want.

Comment: Yes please @RaoslawSzamszur

Comment: Please notice that MultiJob doesn't support Pipeline code and is not planned to do it.

Comment: @yorammi I know that. My thinking was to achieve the same thing that does this MultiJob with pipeline one. And then add a `parallel` block.

Comment: @RaoslawSzamszur, I think your answer is the correct approach (I didn't test your code myself so I can't vote up yet). Still, there are some features of multiJob that cannot be achieved with 'parallel' step, but for what Prashanth Sams needs, it seems good enough.

Comment: @yorammi Would be glad to get an answer for this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53458217/how-to-run-multi-stages-at-the-same-time-using-multi-parallel-blocks

Comment: I've provided an answer for the additional question, I hope it will be good for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't run those jobs in one multijob phase, as an alternative You could use Jenkins pipeline job ([Pipeline docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/)). Parallel stages execution can be achieved by using declarative pipeline [`parallel`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel) block. A dummy example of how your MultiJob could be achieved with pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('MultiJob like stage') {
            parallel {
                stage('Parallel Test') {
                    steps {
                        echo "Here trigger job: allure_behave. Triggered at time:"
                        sh(script: "date -u")
                        // build(job: "allure_behave")
                    }
                }
                stage('Parallel Test 2') {
                    steps {
                        echo "Here trigger job: allure_behave_new. Triggered at time:"
                        sh(script: "date -u")
                        // build(job: "allure_behave_new")
                        echo "Here trigger job: allure_behave_old. Triggered at time:"
                        sh(script: """date -u""")
                        // build(job: "allure_behave_old")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, You have a Stage called `MultiJob like stage` which has substages `Parallel Test` and `Parallel Test 2` just like in your MultiJob. The difference is that both of those sub stages are being executed in parallel.

To trigger other jobs from inside the pipeline job use [`build`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) step:

```
build(job: "job-name")
```

Or if you need to run it with parameters then just add `parameters` `build()` option:

```
build(job: "${JOB_NAME}", parameters: [string(name: 'ENVNAME', value: 'EXAMPLE_STR_PARAM')])
```

Blue Ocean View:

[image: Pipeline Build Blue Ocean View]

Output:

```
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Dummy_pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (MultiJob like stage)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: Parallel Test)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: Parallel Test 2)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Parallel Test)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Parallel Test 2)
[Pipeline] echo
Here trigger job: allure_behave. Triggered at time:
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] echo
Here trigger job: allure_behave_new. Triggered at time:
[Pipeline] sh
+ date -u
Thu Nov 22 18:48:56 UTC 2018
+ date -u
Thu Nov 22 18:48:56 UTC 2018
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] echo
Here trigger job: allure_behave_old. Triggered at time:
[Pipeline] sh
+ date -u
Thu Nov 22 18:48:56 UTC 2018
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Is this alternative valid for your use  case?

Regards